# GraalVM native-image compile Java libraries into iOS framework/libraries

Tags: ios, jvm, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, substratevm

GraalVM native-image allow us to convert Java libraries into local executable. It also allow to compile to shared library as mentioned https://www.graalvm.org/docs/Native-Image/user/README

> An native image can be built as a standalone executable, which is the
> default, or as a shared library by passing --shared to native-image.
> For an image to be useful, it needs to have at least one entry point
> method.

The closest thread I found is this one https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/373, but still can't find any guide to do so for iOS, is that possible? Any guide I can follow?

Comment: Looks like it's implemented as of now: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/373#issuecomment-901909631

Answer (score 0):

It’s not currently possible, and it sounds like it’s not planned to be supported.

The Graal native build requires being built on the same platform that it will run on, since it depends on loading information about the current system. There’s more information about it in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/407